# Can I convert smalldatetime to datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert a smalldatetime date to datetime, and save it into another table. but I got an error like this "The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_tblCourseEnrolment". The conflict occurred in database "BSGDATA", table "dbo.tblCourseEnrolment". The statement has been terminated."

My coding is:

```
tblCourseEnrolment ce = new tblCourseEnrolment();
var neisclientcourse = (from c5 in db.TblNeisCourses where c5.NeisCourseID ==     Convert.ToInt32(enq.enquiryExpectedNEISCourseID) select c5).First();
string time = neisclientcourse.NCStartDate.ToString();
ce.CourseStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
db.tblCourseEnrolments.InsertOnSubmit(ce);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

neisclientcourse.NCStartDate is smalldatetime type, I want to convert it to datetime and save it into tblCourseEnrolment.CourseStartDate table. But the CourseStartDate is datetime type.

Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem with your date conversion. It looks like an insert value is out of range. If it is the date you can try copying the value of `string time` and manually inserting that with a sql insert on the query console. This post might help you narrow the problem down http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496048/sql-server-error-the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-check-constraint

Comment: What does the check constraint `CK_tblCourseEnrolment` enforce?   You need to figure out why that is failing.

Comment: Hi Jasen, thanks for your replying. I have tried
SELECT
name, definition 
FROM
    sys.check_constraints
WHERE
    name = 'ck_tblCourseEnrolment'
But it showed me a blank list. Is there any other way to check ck_tblCourseEnrolment? Thank you very much. @Jasen

Comment: Hi shf301, thanks for your replying. Is there any way to check ck_tblCourseEnrolment's constraint? Thank you very much. @shf301

Comment: Examine the create table script for `tblCourseEnrolment`.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, I will look at the create script. @Jasen